# Stomp.js secure conneciton || Rabbitmq javascript client secure connection

Tags: rabbitmq, stompjs

Is there any way to connect to rabbitmq without rabbit server username and password on javascript.

I don't wanna use this unsecure way

```
  var client = Stomp.overWS('ws://localhost:61614/stomp');
  client.connect(login, passcode, connectCallback);
```

Answer (score 3):

At some level, the stomp connection will require a username/password.  The way to secure the connection is to create a special limited RabbitMQ user with the minimum set of permissions required.  You can see details of the permissions options on the [RabbitMQ ACL page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html).

Additionally, if you don't want to pass a username/password from the stomp client, you can set a "default user" which is used with an anonymous stomp connection.  See the "Default User" section of the [RabbitMQ STOMP page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html).

However, be aware that while you aren't passing a username/password from the client, the client will still have all the permissions on the RabbitMQ broker that the "default user" has.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer, if i made all user as guest user then i have another problem. I need authentication for user does not be able to subscribe another user's queue or exchange. I mean client connect to rabbitmq server (to your answer as a guest user) then subscribe to an exchange via routing key. I need to check is this user can be able to subscribe with this routing key. How can i fixed this problem.

Comment: @V.B.it is a "default user", which should not be the same as the user with the `guest` username.  Instead, it would be a user with a different username and specifically assigned permissions.  However, you can only have one "default user", so I'm not sure it would work in your case.  Is there a reason you can't create one user per stomp user with very limited permissions?  Then you could connect as that user (with `client.connect(username, password, connectCallback)`), but because the user only has limited permissions, it wouldn't matter that the end user knew the username/password.